# How do I create array text boxes in Angular 2 and How to send array text boxes values to component

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

I'm using reactive forms and wanted to create a number of array fields like

```
<input type="text" formControlName="prices[]" id="" class="form-control price-packages">
```

Or you can see here is my form like:

```
<form [formGroup]="createPackageForm" (ngSubmit)="createPackage(createPackageForm.value)">
    <input type="text"
           formControlName="prices[]"
           class="form-control price-packages"/>
    <input
            type="text" formControlName="prices[]" class="form-control price-packages">
    <input type="text"
           formControlName="prices[]"
           class="form-control price-packages"/>
    <input
            type="text" formControlName="prices[]" class="form-control price-packages"/>

    <input type="submit"
           class="button btn btn-success"
           value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Help me please.

Comment: You want an array? Use `FormArray` instead of `FormControl`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You to use FormArray instead of FormControl.
In your html change:

```
<form [formGroup]="createPackageForm" (ngSubmit)="createPackage(createPackageForm.value)">

   <div formArrayName="prices">
       <div *ngFor="let price of createPackageForm.get('prices').controls; let r=index;">
           <div [formGroupName]="r">
                <td><input type="text" formControlName="price-package"></td>
           </div>
       </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

And in your ts you need to add a FormArray into your createPackageForm.

`this.createPackageForm.addControl('prices', new FormArray());`

Check this article for more details:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/how-to-build-nested-model-driven-forms-in-angular-2